# How to write jenkinsfile that will access openshift and run few commands

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, jenkins-groovy, openshift-3

I am new to Jenkins, can someone help me to write Jenkinsfile that access openshift run few of commands, and return the report
I know commands to run  manually in open shift but don't know how to do in Jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few good introductions available on how to access OpenShift using the OpenShift Jenkins Plugin or on how to run generic commands using `sh`:

- [Using OpenShift Pipeline Plugin with External Jenkins](https://www.openshift.com/blog/using-openshift-pipeline-plugin-external-jenkins)
- [Building Declarative Pipelines with OpenShift DSL Plugin](https://www.openshift.com/blog/building-declarative-pipelines-openshift-dsl-plugin)
- More generic: [Jenkins Pipeline: running external programs with sh](https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-running-external-programs)